# How to backup/Save as Template SharePoint 2013 online public site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have E3 online account and have the public web site. I have deployed several sandbox solutions to that site and now I want to get the backup of that site. I have tried several methods to get the back up or the save the site as template. but the getting backup is impossible. Can anybody tell me how to save this site as template with all the data within it(specially Pages library).

Comment: Good question. I do not know of a  backup cmdlet that is available yet for office 365 sharepoint version.

Comment: No commandlet but have you tried from SharePoint Designer? To be honest, we don't use the web site so I'm not sure if you get access to it from Designer.

Comment: Yes, The thing is SharePoint Designer 2013 does not allows to connect SharePoint online public site. Therefore this is also not working.